# Don't splatter tags all over the house (Rename [splatter-house-3] to [splatterhouse-3])

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

We currently have [splatterhouse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatterhouse) and [splatter-house-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatter-house-3) tags, but the [original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splatterhouse) and [successor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splatterhouse_3) games consistently use the "Splatterhouse" name without a space.

[splatter-house-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatter-house-3) should be renamed to [splatterhouse-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatterhouse-3), both to match the name of its game and to harmonize with the tag for the other game in the series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renamed the tag to [splatterhouse-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatterhouse-3) and [splatter-house-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatter-house-3) is now a synonym.